# How can I access object variables deep in MS-Word's Object Model using Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, ms-word

I'm just starting to scratch the surface with the Word Object Model, and have been studying MSDN with is rich with examples in VB and C#. Unfortunately, I'm working with Powershell 2.0, and have found no good examples that help me understand how to get at the data I need. Also, please forgive some of the terminology I use...it may not be accurate; please let me know the proper terminology if I use an improper term so I can improve clarity in future questions. Consider this script:

```
$global:word  = new-object -ComObject Word.Application 
$word.Visible = $False 
$testfile     = "\\path\to\file\foo.doc"
$doc          = $word.Documents.Open($testfile) 
$hyperlinks   = @($doc2.Hyperlinks)
$hyperlinks        # console output
$word.Quit()
```

`$doc` has lots of, for lack of a better term, metadata...things that I can assign to variables via `$foo1 = $doc.Fullname`, `$foo2 = $doc.HasPassword` etc. There are also metadata fields which contain additional LISTS of information -- I believe these are Runtime Callable Wrappers (RCWs) -- which have a value of `System.__ComObject`. The code above pulls the list-of-links object, assigns it to an array called `$hyperlinks`, and when printed to the console, yields a series of records like this, each record representing a hyperlink in `foo.doc`.

```
Application       : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass
Creator           : 1297307460
Parent            : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass
Name              : javascript:TextPopup(this)
AddressOld        : javascript:TextPopup(this)
Type              : 0
Range             : System.__ComObject
Shape             : 
SubAddressOld     : 
ExtraInfoRequired : False
Address           : javascript:TextPopup(this)
SubAddress        : 
EmailSubject      : 
ScreenTip         : 
TextToDisplay     : IVR-generated calls
Target            :
```

Here's where I run into some problems. First, I cannot seem to access any of the RCW's within other RCW's as variables. I can dump data, but not assign it to a specific variable. For instance, I have been unable to generate any console output that represents the detailed contents of `Range` inside a `Hyperlink` record. I've tried

```
$ranges     = @($hyperlinks.Range)     # no output displays
$ranges     = @($doc.hyperlinks.Range) # no output displays 
$ranges     = @($doc.Range)            # yields the following

MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range Range(System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Start, System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo
                      ken=b77a5c561934e089 End)}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range Range(System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Start, System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTok
                      en=b77a5c561934e089 End)
Name                : Range
IsInstance          : True
```

I can output lists of individual values in a `System.__ComObject` by using `foreach` to populate an array as such.

```
$hyperlinks | %{ $_.address }
$hyperlinks | %{ $_.SubAddress }
$hyperlinks | %{ $_.TextToDisplay }
```

My problem lies in assigning these values to variables. In the grand scheme, I'm trying to generate a report that will output a CSV file containing

```
$doc.FullName; $doc.Hyperlinks.Address; $doc.Hyperlinks.SubAddress; $doc.Hyperlinks.TextToDisplay;
```

and have been unable to assign values in the `$hyperlinks` array to specific fields. I would like to do something like this pseudocode:

```
$o01 = $doc.FullName
$o02 = $hyperlinks | %{ $_.address }
$o03 = $hyperlinks | %{ $_.SubAddress }
$o04 = $hyperlinks | %{ $_.TextToDisplay }
$out = $o01 + ";" + $o02 + ";" + $o03 + ";" + $o4 
$ofl = "outPutFile.csv"
$out | Out-File $ofl -append
```

to generate

```
foo1.doc;foo2.html;;"Foo"
foo1.doc;foo3.html;foo2.html;"Foo again"
foo1.doc;foo4.html;foo3.html;"More Foo"
foo2.doc;foo5.html;foo1.html;"Foo"
foo2.doc;foo6.html;foo2.html;"Foo again"
foo3.doc;foo7.html;"More Foo"
```

where `$doc` is repeated in column 1 for each instance of `address`, `subaddress` and `TextToDisplay" appearing in the`$hyperlinks` array associated with that document. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using separate variables, try creating single objects. Assuming $docs contains an array of all document objects you want to process, try something like this:

```
$results = $docs | % {
   $docName = $_.FullName
   $_.Hyperlinks | % {
      New-Object -TypeName PSObject @Property @{
         DocName = $docName;
         Address = $_.address;
         SubAddress = $_.SubAddress;
         TextToDisplay = $_.TextToDisplay
      }
   }
}

$results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Out-File $ofl
```

I don't have Word installed on the system I'm on now, so the code may require some tweaking to get the correct property names in place.

Comment: A splendid and elegant solution. I had no idea that `New-Object` existed. I'll have to research that. Thanks for the pointer.